# SQL Server 2016 Management Studio doesn't keep line numbers

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I can't get SQL Server 2016 Management Studio to remember that I want line numbers. Every time I open an instance, I have to turn line numbers on, but when I open a new instance, they've been turned off again.

Does anyone know how to make them stay on permanently or whether this is a bug within SSMS?

Comment: This seems to have fixed itself, not sure why

Comment: I am having this issue too. You are the only other person who has said this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer to this question was already given, i was looking for how to put line numbers on the editor and the answer was not given, so here it is!

> Step1: Go to Tools > Options.
>
> Step2: In the Options dialog box navigate to Text Editor >
>   Transact-SQL > General.
>
> Step 3: Check “Line Numbers” and click on “OK” Now, when a query
>   window is opened Line Numbers will be displayed